# Error on install the package Spdep in Rstudio

Tags: r

I was trying to install Spdep on Rstudio and this message appeared, I tried to install the package 'sf' and the same message appears

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘sf’ is not available for package ‘spdep’
* removing ‘/home/lua03/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/spdep’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘spdep’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: I believe this error message is telling you that you need "spdep" package first. Try to load the "spdep" package With dependence=TRUE. I get this type of message when I need a supporting package OR a library for Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, i gonna try. Thanks.

Comment: im tried this command line: install.packages("sf",dependencies = TRUE), but is not worked.